Cannot create new Azure VM
Creating a new VM with New-AZVM -name "testvm" cmdlet results in the error:

New-AzVM: The client 'f5a68dde-2f3c-45a6-ae2c-cf6338f13389' with object id 'f5a68dde-2f3c-45a6-ae2c-cf6338f13389' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read' over scope '/subscriptions/7ade4c7f-7aad-46c2-bd47-74bf2a2a5d23/resourceGroups/Dungvm2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/Dungvm2' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

I have owner permission on my Azure account id, and I was able to create a new VM through the Azure portal. Could you please help to see what I need to do?
Many Thanks!

Even though you have owner permissions on your Azure account, the issue might be related to the specific role assignments or scopes within your subscription.

Navigate to Subscriptions.
Select your subscription.
Click on Access control (IAM).
Check the role assignments to ensure your account has the necessary permissions.

Unfortunately, azure lacks the functionality to execute all these on the CLI, so use azure PowerShell for these operations.
Azure PowerShell:
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId <your-object-id>

If permissions were recently granted, refresh your credentials by logging out and back in to ensure the latest permissions are in effect.
Disconnect-AzAccount
Connect-AzAccount

Make sure that you have the required permissions at the resource group level.
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName "Dungvm2" -ObjectId <your-object-id>

If you are using a service principal to create the VM, make sure that the service principal has the necessary role assignments.
Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId <your-service-principal-id>
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId <your-service-principal-id>

Ensure that the scope mentioned in the error message is correct and exists.
Get-AzResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/7ade4c7f-7aad-46c2-bd47-74bf2a2a5d23/resourceGroups/Dungvm2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/Dungvm2"

Make sure the New-AzVM command is correctly formatted and all required parameters are correctly specified.(enable detailed logging for the command to get more information)
$DebugPreference='Continue'
New-AzVM -Name "testvm" -ResourceGroupName "Dungvm2" -Location "EastUS" -Credential (Get-Credential)

By now you should know what is causing the issue.
Good luck!
